# Alternatives for layout that depends on LinearLayout weight

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm trying to make a UI that, as of now, leverages LinearLayout and nesting of these.

This is more or less what I'm trying to accomplish.

`+----------------------------------+
|Overlay Text                      |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|              IMAGE               |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
|Overlay Text    |Overlay Text     |
|                |                 |
|                |                 |
|                |     IMAGE       |
|                |                 |
|                |                 |
|                |                 |
|     IMAGE      +-----------------+
|                |                 |
|                |                 |
|                |                 |
|                |     BUTTON      |
|                |                 |
|                |                 |
+----------------+-----------------+`

The main issue is that the use the `centerCrop` property, so the container panels are a fixed size.

I was able to get this working but I've read that performance can take a hit with multiple nested LinearLayouts due to the recalculation of the nested views' messurements. However I've seen no other way of doing this.

Here's my xml if you wanna take a look. Any help would be great.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainOuterLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/shirtRelativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/shirtImageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/shirt_red"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:text="IF THIS"
            android:id="@+id/shirtTextView"
            style="@style/overlayTextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pantsRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pantsImageView"
                android:src="@drawable/blue_pants"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            <TextView
                android:text="WEAR THIS"
                android:id="@+id/pantsTextView"
                style="@style/overlayTextView" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomRightLinearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/shoesRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/shoesImageView"
                    android:src="@drawable/shoes"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="AND THAT"
                    android:id="@+id/shoesTextView"
                    style="@style/overlayTextView" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Roll Again"
                android:id="@+id/reloadOutfitButton"
                android:background="#b19636"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your view tree isn't that deep.  You should be fine unless you are targeting very old devices running 2.*

Comment: what is your exact problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Good news now we have the got the alternative for the nested LinearLayout weight property from android's `percent support Library`

[Demo HERE !](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

[GitHub Project HERE !](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample)

Consider this simple layout.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff7acfff"
        android:text="20% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="80%-50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Some complex tile layout we can create are:

[image: tile layout]